# How should i use stored procedures in EF to return a simple list with fields from 2 entities

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to EF but i've managed to set up several entities with relationships etc. Now i need to query the database to return a list of "cases" for the current user. I would normally use a stored procedure for this which i've created however the stored procedure returns results which arent entities in the EF its a subset of fields from 2 different tables. How do i achieve this? Any links to tutorials etc would be most welcome.

To summarise i have 2 entities and i want to execute a stored procedure which returns a set of columns which are a collection of fields from both of the entities.

Comment: check this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231.aspx you can import the stored proc or a function and specify what kind of type it returns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create class containing properties with the same names (and types) as columns in your stored procedure's result set and use `ExecuteStoreQuery` to get materialized result from your SP. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358769.aspx) are some examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to the stored procedure approach you can import the stored procedure into your domain model and use the EF design tools to obtain the shape of the stored procedure result set and create a CLR type that reprsents the result set. You can then create a method (via the designer) on your context class that calls this stored procedure and returns an enumerable of this CLR type.

On the other hand,if the two tables are related, you can consider writing a LINQ query that projects the same fields.